# NiFi: Why Does My User Have Insufficient Permissions?

Tags: docker, ssl, apache-nifi

I am following the steps in the "Standalone Instance, Two-Way SSL" section of  https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi. However, when I visit the NiFi page, my user has insufficient permissions. Below is the process I am using:

**Generate self-signed certificates**

```sh
mkdir conf

docker exec \
  -ti toolkit \
  /opt/nifi/nifi-toolkit-current/bin/tls-toolkit.sh \
    standalone \
    -n 'nifi1.bluejay.local' \
    -C 'CN=admin,OU=NIFI'

docker cp toolkit:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/nifi-cert.pem        conf
docker cp toolkit:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/nifi-key.key         conf

docker cp toolkit:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/nifi1.bluejay.local  conf

docker cp toolkit:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/CN=admin_OU=NIFI.p12      conf
docker cp toolkit:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/CN=admin_OU=NIFI.password conf

docker stop toolkit
```

**Import client certificate to browser**

Import the `.p12` file into your browser.

**Update /etc/hosts**

Add "127.0.0.1 nifi1.bluejay.local" to the end of your /etc/hosts file.

**Define a NiFi network**

```sh
docker network create --subnet=10.18.0.0/16 nifi
```

**Run NiFi in a container**

```sh
docker run -d \
  -e AUTH=tls \
  -e KEYSTORE_PATH=/opt/certs/keystore.jks \
  -e KEYSTORE_TYPE=JKS \
  -e KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=$(grep keystorePasswd conf/nifi1.bluejay.local/nifi.properties | cut -d'=' -f2) \
  -e TRUSTSTORE_PATH=/opt/certs/truststore.jks \
  -e TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=$(grep truststorePasswd conf/nifi1.bluejay.local/nifi.properties | cut -d'=' -f2) \
  -e TRUSTSTORE_TYPE=JKS \
  -e INITIAL_ADMIN_IDENTITY="CN=admin,OU=NIFI" \
  -e NIFI_WEB_PROXY_CONTEXT_PATH=/nifi \
  -e NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST=nifi1.bluejay.local \
  --hostname nifi1.bluejay.local \
  --ip 10.18.0.10 \
  --name nifi \
  --net nifi \
  -p 8443:8443 \
  -v $(pwd)/conf/nifi1.bluejay.local:/opt/certs:ro \
  -v /data/projects/nifi-shared:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/ls-target \
  apache/nifi
```

**Visit Page**

When you visit http://localhost:8443/nifi, you'll be asked to select a certificate. Select the certificate (e.g. admin) that you imported.

At this point, I am seeing:

```
Insufficient Permissions
Unknown user with identity 'CN=admin, OU=NIFI'. Contact the system administrator.
```

In the examples I am seeing, there is no mention of this issue or how to resolve it.

How are permissions assigned to the Initial Admin Identity?

Comment: The identity "CN=admin,OU=NIFI" must has a space after the comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a space at line

```
-e INITIAL_ADMIN_IDENTITY="CN=admin,OU=NIFI"
```

See the error msg.